# React JS - How to add object inside object

Tags: reactjs, object, state

I have this code in constructor :

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        recipient: {
          lat: -6.173752,
          lon: 106.8925773
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to add this to **recipient** :

```
var temp = {
  address: 'example street',
  phone: '+623123131321'
}
```

How to add temp variable to **recipient** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override your state using the spread operator

```
this.state = {
    recipient: {
        ...temp,
        lat: -6.173752,
        lon: 106.8925773
    }
}
```

Or outside the constructor using `setState`

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   recipient: {...prevState.recipient, ...temp}
}))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to merge the state values

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    recipient: {...prevState.recipient, ...temp}
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler solution is to directly destructure recipients current state into the new state like this.

```
this.setState({
    recipient: {...this.state.recipient, ...temp}
})
```